# Why is this object regarded as integer when I think it's a list?

Tags: python

This is a practice problem, which reads:

Define a procedure that takes in a string of numbers from 1-9 and outputs a list with the following parameters:

1. Every number in the string should be inserted into the list.
2. If a number x in the string is less than or equal to the preceding
       number y, the number x should be inserted into a sublist. Continue
       adding the following numbers to the sublist until reaching a number
       z that is greater than the number y. Then add this number z to the
       normal list and continue.

Examples:

```
string = '543987'; result = [5,[4,3],9,[8,7]]

string= '987654321'; result = [9,[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]]

string = '455532123266'; result = [4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], 6, [6]]

string = '123456789'; result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

My code is as follows:

```
def numbers_in_lists(s):
    n=len(s)
    p=[]
    i=0
    while i<=n-1:
        p.append(int(s[i]))
        i=i+1

    r=[p[0]]    
    if p[1]<=p[0]:
        r.append([p[1]])
    else:
        r.append(p[1])
    if n<=2:
        return r
    j=2
    while j<=n-1:
        if p[j]<=p[j-1]:
            if p[j-1]<=p[j-2]:
                r[-1].append(p[j])
            else:
                r.append(p[j])
        else:
            if p[j]<=p[j-2]:
                r[-1].append(p[j])
            else:
                r.append(p[j])
        j=j+1
    return r
```

When I tried to run `print (numbers_in_lists('543987'))`, I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lesson14Quiz3.py", line 33, in <module>
    print (numbers_in_lists(string))
  File "Lesson14Quiz3.py", line 20, in numbers_in_lists
    r[-1].append(p[j])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The problem seems to be with this line: `r[-1].append(p[j])`. But I think when the previous conditions are satisfied, `r[-1]` should not be an integer, but a list.

Comment: Are you contradicting with `python`? What we can tell you is "print", "debug", etc. But the point I'm making is, if python says it's int, be sure it's `int`.

Comment: `r` is a list. `r[len(r)-1]` is an item of that list and apparently an item of type `int`.

Comment: @Adelin Python saying it is "int" so it is "int" , I trust Python as you do but I am trying to look at list in the way how Python look at it. Thanks.

Comment: just a quick note for python. To access last element of list, instead of using `r[len(r) -1]` you can use `r[-1]`

Comment: @Esser420 Yes, this is much simpler. I have amended my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Some of you seem to have misunderstood me. What I am trying to say is that, given how I write my code, if the conditions before `r[-1].append(p[j])` are met, then I believe `r[-1]` would be a list, to be more specific, a list in a list.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis What if the last element of `r` is itself a list? In this case, do you still call this element an integer?

Comment: @failbetter your supposition is correct. I have edited my answer to show an example of this. The real problem here is that your code logic is attempting to append to an integer, when it should not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code:

```
r[len(r)-1].append(p[j])
```

breaks down to this:

```
r: your overall list
len(r): an integer value based on calculation of the length of r 
-1: also an integer value
```

Let's pretend `len(r)` is 5.

Thus 5 - 1 is equal to 4.

`r[4]` uses Python indexing to identify a specific element in the list `r`. Specifically, the element at position 4, starting by counting at index 0.

If the element at position 4 is a number like an integer (rather than a sublist), then Python cannot append anything to the number, cause numbers do not have an `.append()` method.

### Example:

Presuming we have a list that looks like:

```
r = [7, 13, 42]
```

And we want to append a 99.

```
>>> r.append(99)
[7, 13, 42, 99]
```

But if we index to one of the integers within `r`, as opposed to a sublist within `r`, we get the error.

```
>>> r[1].append(99)     # r[1] is the value 13.
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Lastly, if the item we are indexing to is a sublist, then `append()` will work just fine.

```
# presume r now equals: [7, 13, 42, 99, [1]]
#    and we want to append a 1337
>>> r[-1].append(1337)     # r[-1] is the last value and is a sublist
[7, 13, 42, 99, [1, 1337]]
```

### Possible solution:

This may help solve your problem and may make it easier to troubleshoot the code.

```
def numbers_in_lists(s):
    # use a list comprehension to simplify the process of making a list of
    #     integers
    p = [int(x) for x in s]

    # set two sentinel values to help control the code logic/decisions
    flag = False
    previous_high = 0

    # create an empty list
    r = []

    # iterate over all the digits...
    for num in p:

        # the code logic is broken into three tests 
        if num <= previous_high and not flag:
            # if flag is False create a sublist
            r.append([num])
            flag = True

        elif num < previous_high and flag:
            # if flag is True append to a sublist we previously created
            r[-1].append(num) 

        elif num > previous_high:
            # Otherwise, append to the main list again   
            r.append(num)
            previous_high = num
            flag = False

    return r
```

### Sample outputs (using the strings the OP provided):

```
>>> numbers_in_list('543987')
[5, [4, 3], 9, [8, 7]]

>>> numbers_in_list('987654321')
[9, [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]

>>> numbers_in_list('455532123266')
[4, 5, [5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], 6, [6]]

>>> numbers_in_list('123456789')
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Only way this answer could've been better is if you'd keep following the trail back to the original `s`

Comment: What I am trying to say is that, given how I write my code, if the conditions before r[-1].append(p[j]) are met, then I believe r[-1] would be a list, to be more specific, a list in a list.  In this case, can I apply `append` to this list which itself is the last element of another list?

Comment: If the item you are referencing is a sublist, then, absolutely, you can append to a sublist within a list.
At the moment, your code is not accurately determining whether the item you are pointing at is a sublist.

Comment: I understand all of what you said, but this is not what I'm asking for. My real question is, I believe that when `p[j]<=p[j-1]` and `p[j-1]<=p[j-2]` are both True, then the last element of `r` at this time should be a list. However, the error message seems to suggest otherwise. I just have no idea where my code went wrong.

Comment: @failbetter I have tried to parse through your code several times to find exactly where it breaks down and my poor brain struggles with keeping track of what is stored at `p[j-1]` versus what is stored at `p[j-2]`, etc. As we cycle through the digits, we need to detect only three real conditions. In the code I suggest, I tried to capture the status of the conditions using flags versus using a diverse collection of indexes. My sense is that this simplifies the thinking about the problem and the code itself.

Comment: You code is lucid. The "previous_high" variable also enlightened me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

`r` is a list. So, you can safely do `r.append(p[1])`. But `r[len(r)-1]` is an element in the list `r` at position `len(r)-1` which is an integer, not a list. `r[len(r)-1].append(p[j])` is performing `append` on `int` which is not possible. Hence this error.

**For example:**
Consider `r = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

```
>>> r.append(6)
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>>> r[5].append(7) # here r[5] is 6 which is an integer
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

With your code, the input `s ='4655....'` gives you this error. Because you append `4`,then you see `6` which is greater so you add it as next element. Then you see `5`. Your code will add it as an element. Then again a `5` comes.  **Here is the problem**. At this step, `p[j]<=p[j-1]` (5<=5) and `p[j-1]<=p[j-2]` (5<=6) are true. So, `r[-1].append(p[j])` is done where `r[-1]` is `5` (append operation on 5 which is actually an integer).

Please do a traverse through your code. There is logical error, which results in appending to an `integer`.

**Two problems:**

**Problem 1:** In your code, within the `while j<=n-1:` loop, you are not creating any sublists in the list `r`. When `p[j]<=p[j-1]` is true and `p[j-1]<=p[j-2]` is false, actually you need to create a sublist with the item `p[j]`. You instead added `p[j]` as simply an element in the list.

**Problem 2:** Your code only checks for last three elements in list. This causes a new item to insert as a new element in the list when it should actually be an element in the sublist.

**SOLUTION:**

```
def numbers_in_lists(s):
    n=len(s)
    p=[]
    i=0
    while i<=n-1:
        p.append(int(s[i]))
        i=i+1

    r=[p[0]]    
    if p[1]<=p[0]:
        r.append([p[1]])
        k = p[1]
    else:
        r.append(p[1])
        k = -1
    if n<=2:
        return r
    j=2
    while j<=n-1:
        if p[j]<=p[j-1]:
            if p[j-1]<=p[j-2] or p[j]<=k:
                r[-1].append(p[j])
            else:
                r.append([p[j]])
                k = p[j]
        else:
            if p[j]<=p[j-2] or p[j]<=k:
                r[-1].append(p[j])
            else:
                r.append(p[j])
        j=j+1
    return r
```

**Outputs:**

```
'543987' ->  [5, [4, 3], 9, [8, 7]]

'987654321' ->  [9, [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]

'455532123266'  ->  [4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], 6, [6]]

'123456789'  ->  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I understand all of what you said, but this is not what I'm asking for. My real question is, I believe that when `p[j]<=p[j-1] `and `p[j-1]<=p[j-2]` are both True, then the last element of `r` at this time should be a list. However, the error message seems to suggest otherwise. I just have no idea where my code went wrong.

Comment: Please traverse with `string = '4655...'` and you will know where you went wrong. :)

Comment: I've modified your code. This does not show your error and works good for all cases. :) Please let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: Your answer has pointed me to my error. So it is helpful :) I haven't yet taken a look at your code, as I want to solve this problem by myself.